# Initialisations in the class

Tags: java, class

Why does java allow instance variables to be initialized in the class itself? I mean there is no memory allocated to the instance variables unless we have created the object of that class, then how can they be initialized without allocation of memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initializing instance variables directly does not initialize them before creating the object - it's just syntactic sugar that Java provides to save you another line in the constructor. For example, the following snippet:

```
public class MyClass {
    int member = 7;
}
```

Is equivilant to

```
public class MyClass {
    int member;

    public MyClass() {
        memeber = 7;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those instance variables are actually initialized just prior to execution of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point of memory allocation to instance variable without creating object of that class. So when you create an object only just before constructor execution ,all initialization ,init block execution happens and memory is allocated.

Answer (score 0):

the whole initialization hierarchy is a big long to spell out here. For your case, doing

```
public class MyClass {
    int member = 7;
}
```

just is a directive to the runtime to initialize `member` and set its initial value as 7. At a finer grained level, the variable is initialized to its default value and then assigned the new value. its an atomic action. But like others said this happens before constructor call. So all local variables are initialized before the runtime calls your constructor. Likewise all statics are called before the variables like `member` are initialized and so forth

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, we have a class named `Auto`:

```
public class Auto {
    int numberOfDoors = 4;
    int numberOfWheels = 4;
    //..
}
```

**Sequence follow:**

**1.** Creating an object named Obj, using "new" operator:

```
Auto fordMustang = new Auto();
```

**2.** Memory has been allocated.

**3.** Then, the constructor is invoked after.

Instance variables in class itself is **syntactic sugar**. Really, these variables not exists till create new object.